# Connecting to WS-Security protected Soap Web Service with PHP

Tags: soap, wsdl

I have this wsdl file witch is not password protected and I need to call it via php soap client:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:afe4="http://gsis.ggps.interoperability/Afe4Interface">
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd' >
<wsse:Username>****************************</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText'>*****************************</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
```

Other parameters here
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

I am trying to connect via php soapheader:

```
    class WsseAuthHeader extends SoapHeader {

    private $wss_ns = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';

    function __construct($user, $pass, $ns = null) {
    if ($ns) {
        $this->wss_ns = $ns;
    }

    $auth = new stdClass();
    $auth->Username = new SoapVar($user, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL,     $this->wss_ns); 
    $auth->Password = new SoapVar($pass, XSD_STRING, NULL, $this->wss_ns, NULL, $this->wss_ns);

    $username_token = new stdClass();
    $username_token->UsernameToken = new SoapVar($auth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'UsernameToken', $this->wss_ns); 

    $security_sv = new SoapVar(
    new SoapVar($username_token, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'UsernameToken', $this->wss_ns),
    SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $this->wss_ns, 'Security', $this->wss_ns);
    parent::__construct($this->wss_ns, 'Security', $security_sv, true);
    }
  ******************  }

    $wsse_header = new WsseAuthHeader($username, $password);
```

but it replies with

> A security error was encountered when verifying the message

which according to the manual means wrong user or password.

Via postman I can connect.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: When i call a certain function it replies "A security error was encountered when verifying the message" and it does'n bring any data.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that setting header to raw data solve the problem.
Thanks for your time!!!

Comment: Make sure to select this as the correct answer so anyone else with the same issue can find it easily. good work :)

Also maybe edit the question to include the error message.